# Animate one object towards another

Tags: jquery, gsap

Using either jQuery animate, or some GSAP equivalent, is it possible to set the destination top/left of one object to the top/left of another object?  I have two objects at opposite sides of the screen that will move towards each other (though one or the other may experience some variation) and it feels like the animation would run much smoother if I used GSAP than if I simply updated the top and left values in an infinite loop.

I'm wandering if it's possible via code something like:

```
$("#img1").animate({
    top: $("#img2").css("top"),
    left: $("#img2").css("left"),
}, 1000);

$("#img2").animate({
    top: $("#img1").css("top"),
    left: $("#img1").css("left"),
}, 1000);
```

Is this possible?  The above did not work for me.

Comment: If they're going to move at the same speed then they're going to meet at a point half way between their start points.

Comment: As it currently stands, your elements would actually switch positions. You probably want to update their destination on `step`

Comment: @gvee They will be moving at different speeds, and may need to move off the direct path to avoid other objects, so the new target coordinates would need calculated continually.  I can do this in a loop that fires 20-30 times per second, but I worry that will perform more poorly.